# heaviside of 1/x

Tags: calculus

When I plot the function $H(\frac{1}{x})$ through sympy and WolframAlpha, the result is exactly the same as plotting $H(x)$. Is then true the following statement?
$$ H\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=H(x) $$

Comment: Have you tried to verify the claim using the *definition* of $H$?  What if $x=0$ ?

Comment: It's clear that it does not work when $x=0$ and that's why it bothers me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming $x\neq0$ (otherwise $1/x$ may not be defined). If $x>0$, then $1/x>0$ and so $H(x)=H(1/x)=1$. If $x<0$, then $1/x<0$ and so $H(x)=H(1/x)=0$.